# pytest fixture not found on a simple decorator, only on Python 3

Tags: python, pytest, python-decorators

Pytest fails the following testcase with "fixture 'func' not found" on Python 3.7. On Python 2.7, the same code succeeds. In both cases, pytest 4.6.9 is used:

Content of `pytest_decorator_issue/test_issue.py`:

```
import functools

def my_decorator(func):

    def wrapper_func(*args, **kwargs):
        # do something on entry
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        # do something on exit
        return ret

    return functools.update_wrapper(wrapper_func, my_decorator)

@my_decorator
def test_bla():
    # perform some test
    pass
```

Invocation of pytest on Python 3.7:

```
$ pytest pytest_decorator_issue -vv
=============== ... test session starts ...
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.5, pytest-4.6.9, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- .../virtualenvs/pywbem37/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: ...
plugins: requests-mock-1.7.0, cov-2.8.1
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                         

pytest_decorator_issue/test_issue.py::test_bla ERROR                                                                                   [100%]

============ ...  ERRORS ...
____________ ...  ERROR at setup of test_bla ...
file .../pytest_decorator_issue/test_fixture_issue.py, line 3
  def my_decorator(func):
E       fixture 'func' not found
>       available fixtures: cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, cov, doctest_namespace, monkeypatch, no_cover, pytestconfig, record_property, record_testsuite_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, requests_mock, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.

.../pytest_decorator_issue/test_fixture_issue.py:3
============== ...  1 error in 0.01 seconds =================================================================
```

Pytest apparently decides to look for a fixture named 'func' when it sees the argument of the decorator function, but why does it not do that on Python 2.7, and how can I have a simple decorator like this on a pytest test function?

Just for comparison of the versions, on Python 2,7, the relevant pytest output is:

```
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.16, pytest-4.6.9, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- .../virtualenvs/pywbem27/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: ...
plugins: requests-mock-1.7.0, cov-2.8.1
collected 1 item
```

**Update:**

I just found that when using the `functools.wraps` decorator instead of `functools.update_wrapper()`, pytest is happy on both Python 2.7 and 3.7:

```
def my_decorator(func):

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper_func(*args, **kwargs):
        # do something on entry
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        # do something on exit
        return ret

    return wrapper_func
```

Can someone explain this?

Comment: I think the second argument in your call to `update_wrapper` has to be `func` instead of `my_decorator`. Not sure why this works under Python 2, though.

Comment: Thanks much!! It turns out you are right there. Correcting the second argument as you suggested fixed all cases. Feel free to repost your comment as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument in your call to `update_wrapper` has to be `func` instead of `my_decorator`:

```
def my_decorator(func):

    def wrapper_func(*args, **kwargs):
        # do something on entry
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        # do something on exit
        return ret

    return functools.update_wrapper(wrapper_func, func)
```

Not sure why this works under Python 2, though.

Comment: Thanks much!! It turns out you are right there. Correcting the second argument as you suggested fixed all cases.